# Key and lock code [game programming]?

Tags: python-3.x

Metaphorically speaking, I'm learning python in a community college for game programming; and our second assignment is to make a text based game. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to get the code to run if the player has something in their inventory, then display these options or print these options if they don't have that certain item in their inventory.

Comment: Sounds like an entire assignment!

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is what was a very popular type of game a long time ago. The most difficult portion of this type of game is interpreting user input. You can start with a list of possible commands, iterating through each token of the user's input. If I type

> look left

the game can begin by calling a method or function which interprets the available visual data. You will want to look into your database implementation for what is left in relation to the current player's position. The game can respond with

> You see a wooden box on the floor. It is locked.

You get the idea. As the user, I will probably want to check my inventory for a key. You can implement a subroutine in your parser for searching, categorizing, and using your inventory. The key to writing anything like the described program is spending at least twice as much time testing and debugging the game over how much time you spent coding the first working version. The second key is to make sure you are thinking ahead. Example: "How can I modularize the navigation subroutine so that maps can be modified or expanded easily?"

Comment if you have any questions. Good luck coding!

Comment: I tried posting my code but its not letting me. Well is it better to make a list for inventory or a dictionary?

Comment: That is entirely up to you. In my opinion, though, dictionaries are easier to read while editing source code. `self.actions[action](self.inventory[in_use])` is a lot easier to read than `self.actions[offset](self.inventory[offser_2])`.